# How to count entries in excel column only certain number of times?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I’d like to count how many times a certain company is audited according to a certain standard. If a company XYZ in a column F is audited according to a certain standard in a column C more than 3 times, 3 of these companies should count as 1, 2 and 3.
If a company is audited 2 times, it should count as 1 and 2.
If a company is audited only once, it should count as 1.

Here is the example (column G is the desired result):
[image]

I have already a code, which unfortunately does not fulfill all the requirements.

Is it possible to adjust it accordingly?

```
Sub GroupCertificates_MAX3()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim rngDB As Range, vDB As Variant
Dim s1, s2
Dim r As Long, i As Long
Dim k As Long, n As Long

Set Ws = ActiveSheet

Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1)
vDB = rngDB

r = UBound(vDB, 1)
s1 = vDB(1, 2)
s2 = vDB(1, 5)

k = 1
For i = 1 To r
    If vDB(i, 2) = s1 And vDB(i, 5) = s2 Then
        n = n + 1
    Else
        vDB(k, 7) = WorksheetFunction.Min(3, n)
        k = i
        n = 1
        s1 = vDB(i, 2)
        s2 = vDB(i, 5)
    End If
Next i
rngDB = vDB

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a nested dictionaries.  It can be a bit mind bending to realise that a dictionary item can be another dictionary.  Also, without the 'with' syntax things can get very verbose very quickly

```
Public Sub CountUsingDictionaries()

    Dim myCompanies As Variant
    myCompanies = GetColumnArrayFromExcel(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F2:F11"))
    
    Dim myStandard As Variant
    myStandard = GetColumnArrayFromExcel(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1).Range("B2:B11"))
    
    Dim myCounter As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myCounter = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim myResult As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myResult = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim myIndex As Long
    For myIndex = LBound(myCompanies) To UBound(myCompanies)
    
        Dim myCKey As String
        myCKey = myCompanies(myIndex)
        
        Dim mySKey As String
        mySKey = myStandard(myIndex)
        
        If Not myCounter.exists(myCKey) Then
        
            myCounter.Add myCKey, New Scripting.Dictionary
            
        End If
        
        With myCounter.Item(myCKey)
        
            If Not .exists(mySKey) Then
            
                .Add mySKey, 0
                
            End If
            
            .Item(mySKey) = .Item(mySKey) + 1
            
            If .Item(mySKey) > 3 Then
            
                myResult.Add myIndex, " "
                
            Else
            
                myResult.Add myIndex, .Item(mySKey)
                
            End If
            
        End With
        
    Next
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Item(1).Range("G2:G11") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myResult.Items)
        
End Sub


Public Function GetColumnArrayFromExcel(ByVal ipRange As Excel.Range) As Variant
' This is a workaround for an idiosyncracy of Excel which returns a
' 2D variant array when the request is only for a 1D array
' If you need an array from a row then you need two transpose actions

    GetColumnArrayFromExcel = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ipRange.Value)

End Function
```

The code above was tested using

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you so much taking your time for it! Unfortunately, I get an error message "User-defined type not defined". Does it mean I have to bind dictionaries? Sorry, I am a real newbie...

Comment: Yes.  Goto Tools.References and make sure that the box next the Microsoft Scripting Runtime is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with normal excel formulas, but using VBA, and then pasting values. The code will be indeed easier:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'we get last non empty row in column A

Range("F2:F" & LR).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTIFS(R2C2:RC[-4],RC[-4],R2C5:RC[-1],RC[-1])>3,"""",COUNTIFS(R2C2:RC[-4],RC[-4],R2C5:RC[-1],RC[-1]))" 'we calculate
Range("F2:F" & LR) = Range("F2:F" & LR).Value 'we past as values (optional)
```

[image]

In case you want to know, I'm using this formula with dynamic ranges:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:B2;B2;$E$2:E2;E2)>3;"";COUNTIFS($B$2:B2;B2;$E$2:E2;E2))
```